# VBA: ComboBox Change Action

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I know only the Click-Action when using ComboBoxes. Is there also a Change-Action?

Examples: By using the Click-Event Columns A:C will be hidden (ComboBox is ticked). Unclicking will unhide the cells (inside the Click-Event there are if / else statement).

If an other event will hide the Columns A:C so would like the ComboBox will automatically becomes ticked.

Comment: `Is there also a Change-Action?` Yes. `By using the Click-Event Columns A:C will be hidden (ComboBox is ticked). Unclicking will unhide the cells (inside the Click-Event there are if / else statement).` I recommend using `CheckBox` for this.

Comment: I mean an Event similar to `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) ` so if you don't click.